# Strikethrough in chat does not work when message starts with newline

Tags: bug, chat, markdown

Pretty obscure: Strikethrough does not work correctly in chat if the message starts with a newline.

To reproduce, try the following key sequence in a message:

- <kbd>Shift + Enter</kbd> `test ---test--- test` → *send*

Expected: *test <s>test</s> test*

Actual: *test ---test--- test* is output and the leading newline is trimmed.

I only discovered this when I was [trying to figure out strikethrough](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4370098#4370098) in chat and apparently accidentally inserted a newline (still not sure how) before my only correct guess.

I do not know if it is the newline, or if there is some more general criteria. I do know that a leading *space* does not trigger the issue.

Comment: Turns out it's a duplicate given the results of [rene's investigation below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271783/230261) (and it's by-design).